# TCPDF MultiCell with first line indent

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'd like to print some text in a MultiCell, where all lines but the first one would be indented.

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: I want to achieve something like this:]

This is what I have so far: `$this->tcpdf->MultiCell(WIDTH, 0, $myText, "", "L");`

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method to do that, TCPDF offers the usual methods of justifying text which are left, right,center, justify, and default and other methods for vertical alignment.

Take a look at [Multicell TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_005.phps)

You can try writing a custom extention for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use text-indent with a negative value:

```
$this->tcpdf->writeHTML('<p style="text-indent: -10px>foo<p>');
```